# How can i add a shadow in ListTile flutter like 'elevation'

Tags: flutter, dart, shadow, elevation, listtile

I need to add a shadow in my items listTile elements in flutter, but i could not do that with BoxShadow because it is only possible in Container

[image]

this is my listTile:

```
                        child: ListTile(

                          leading: const Icon(Icons.flight_land),
                          tileColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                            side: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),

                          title: Text(
                            snapshot
                                .data!.docChanges[index].doc['nameCourse'],
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              //COLOR DEL TEXTO TITULO
                              color: Colors.blueAccent,
                            ),
                          ),
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 8,
                            horizontal: 16,
                          ),
                        ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
          child: ListTile(
                          leading: const Icon(Icons.flight_land),
                          tileColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                            side: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
        spreadRadius: 5,
        blurRadius: 7,
        offset: Offset(0, 3),
      ),
    ]
                          title: Text(
                            snapshot
                            .data!.docChanges[index].doc['nameCourse'],
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              //COLOR DEL TEXTO TITULO
                              color: Colors.blueAccent,
                            ),
                          ),
                         ),
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 8,
                            horizontal: 16,
                          ),
                        ),
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 9):

You can wrap your `ListTile` widget with `Material` widget and give it shadow.

For example:

```
Material(
  elevation: 20.0,
  shadowColor: Colors.blueGrey,
...
),
```

Answer (score 5):

Try below code hope its help to you.

**Using Card:**

```
Card(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
    side: BorderSide(
      color: Colors.black,
    ),
  ),
  elevation: 16,
  shadowColor: Colors.red,
  child: ListTile(
    leading: const Icon(Icons.flight_land),
    title: Text(
      'Title',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 20,
        //COLOR DEL TEXTO TITULO
        color: Colors.blueAccent,
      ),
    ),
    subtitle: Text(
      'Sub Title',
    ),
    trailing: const Icon(Icons.add),
  ),
),
```

Your result Screen-> [image]

Refer `Card` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Card-class.html)

**Using PhysicalModel:**

```
PhysicalModel(
        color: Colors.white,
        elevation: 18,
        shadowColor: Colors.green,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        child: ListTile(
          leading: const Icon(Icons.flight_land),
          title: Text(
            'Title',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              //COLOR DEL TEXTO TITULO
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
            ),
          ),
          subtitle: Text(
            'Sub Title',
          ),
          trailing: const Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
```

Refer `PhysicalModel` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PhysicalModel-class.html)

Refer `ListTile` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html)

Your Result screen-> [image]

**Using PhysicalShape**

```
PhysicalShape(
        color: Colors.white,
        elevation: 18,
        shadowColor: Colors.yellow,
        clipper: ShapeBorderClipper(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ),
          ),
        child: ListTile(
          leading: const Icon(Icons.flight_land),
          title: Text(
            'Title',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              //COLOR DEL TEXTO TITULO
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
            ),
          ),
          subtitle: Text(
            'Sub Title',
          ),
          trailing: const Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
```

Refer `PhysicalShape` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PhysicalShape-class.html)

Your Result screen-> [image]

**Using Material**

```
Material(
        color: Colors.white,
        elevation: 18,
        shadowColor: Colors.blue,
        child: ListTile(
          leading: const Icon(Icons.flight_land),
          title: Text(
            'Title',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              //COLOR DEL TEXTO TITULO
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
            ),
          ),
          subtitle: Text(
            'Sub Title',
          ),
          trailing: const Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
```

Refer Material [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Material-class.html)

Your Result screen->[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a shadow to the ListTile itself. So a solution can be to wrap it with a container like so

```dart
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white, // Your desired background color
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3), blurRadius: 15),
    ]
  ),
  child: ListTile(
    leading: const Icon(Icons.flight_land),
    tileColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
      side: const BorderSide(
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
    ),
    title: const Text(
      'Text',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 20,
        //COLOR DEL TEXTO TITULO
        color: Colors.blueAccent,
      ),
    ),
    contentPadding:
    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 16),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use card, and put this in card

```
elevation: 16,
  shadowColor: Colors.black,
```